# How to use nested for loops to create a pd.DataFrame filtered by keys from a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries with the most important data being a pandas DataFrame filtered by the keys of each dictionary. So, dict1_key[dict2_key]['df'] = a DataFrame where column1 == dict1_key and column2 == dict2_key. In real life, my data is more complicated, but this trivial example illustrates my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'city': ['NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY'],
        'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
}

letters = {
    'A': {'df': None},
    'B': {'df': None},
    'C': {'df': None}
}

cities = {
    'NY': {},
    'LA': {}
}

for city, outer_dict in cities.items():
    for letter, inner_dict in letters.items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df = df[df['city'] == city]
        df = df[df['letter'] == letter]
        inner_dict['df'] = df
        cities[city][letter] = inner_dict

print(cities['NY']['A'])
```

**Expected output:**
|city|letter|
|----|------|
|NY  |A     |

**Observed output:**
|city|letter|
|----|------|
|LA  |A     |

I can't seem to figure out how to reconfigure it so that cities['NY']['A'] properly prints out NY data and not LA.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand.
I think,you did some reversing, and I don't be sure this is good.
You do loops by two dictonaries, but I think, main loop should be done by data.
You should create df variable only once, and use this as main iterator, receiving columns 'city' and 'letter'

Second problem is construction 'cities' structure. You consequently overwrite the same object. Print all 'cities' structure, using:

```
import json

print(json.dumps(cities, indent=4))
```

do this print after cities[city][letter] = inner_dict , ald observe what is really changed and overwrited.

I don't rule, problem may be in pointer assigments. maybe pointer is assigned, but not usable data.

Please correct me if i wrote any nonsense :)